# Curve contains Regular Points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a curve over arbitrary field $k$. Clear is that every point of $C$ is closed or generic.

My question is why is the set of **regular** points of $C$ always non empty?

Remark: A point $a$ of is regular if and only if $dim(\mathcal{O}_{C,a}) = dim_{\kappa(a)}m_a / m_a^2$

Comment: What is a curve for you? For example, $x^2=0$ in $\mathbb{A}^2=\mathrm{Spec}\, k[x,y]$ is a curve in some notations and it has no regular point.

Comment: one dimensional separated scheme

Comment: The example I gave is a one dimensional separated scheme which has no regular points.

Comment: A reduced scheme of finite type over a (perfect?) field has a nonempty open set of regular points.

Comment: @user45878: Do you have a good reference for a proof?

Comment: It should be in Hartshorne, I can dig it up later.